# Unordered List UL in firefox and IE leaves empty space (item) CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

Here is a very stange problem:

[Screenshoot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2cerouc.jpg)

I made sure that the image sizes are equal, and Chrome displays it correctly. Why not IE and Firefox? Any wolution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height is different from one `li` to another. check that. image sizes are same but `li` height not same in first and second.

so, if you set `height:260px` to your li, it working fine.